# How to save a List<type> in Shared Prefrences

Tags: json, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, saving-data

The list is type `Contact`, which is a Class acquired from `contacts_service` package.

I tried to save it by first `jsonEncode` and then saving it as a List:

```
List<Contact> contacts = [];

void saveContacts() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final encoded = jsonEncode(contacts)
    prefs.setStringList('contactList', encoded);
}
```

and loading it with:

```
void loadContacts(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    contacts = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('contactList'))
```

but I got error `List<dynmaic> instead of List<Contact>`

So I tried converting it to `Map`:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var encoded= jsonEncode(contacts, toEncodable: (c) {
      if (c is Contact) {
        return c.toMap();
      }
    });
    prefs.setStringList('contactList', encoded);
```

and loading:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    contacts =  (jsonDecode(prefs.getString('List'))as List ).map((e) {return 
    Contact.fromMap(e);});
```

but I got `String is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast`

So now I have no idea what else to do.

Note : using `Shared Preferences` and `Json` is not necessary, and will try to use any other packages if they are better with saving this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The error `List<dynamic> instead of List<Contact>` tells you that when you do `jsonDecode(prefs.getString('contactList'))` it's deserialized as a `List<dynamic>`, if you want it to be of type `List<Contact>` you must cast the children to the type you want `map((c) => c as Contact)).toList()`.

Encoding:

```
List<Contact> contacts = [];
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final encoded = jsonEncode(contacts)
prefs.setStringList('contactList', encoded);
```

Decoding:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
contacts = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('contactList')).map((c) => c as Contact)).toList();
```

Comment: I am getting `type  _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'Contact' in type cast`, also`map` doesn't show up when typing manually so I think there is something wrong with the structure of your code @Daniel Evangelista

Comment: The code above is if you encode it from a `List<Contact>` and not a Map.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what do you mean, can you provide an example @Daniel Evangelista